# I want to permanently change the background color to white and the text color to black in Command Prompt

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I can change it for one session, but it always reverts back to white on black. How can I change it ***permanently***?

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean Windows? Change screen text and screen backgrounds

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

That depends on our OS.

In windows 7:

- Start a cmd.exe
- Right click on the title bar
- select either `defaults` or `properties`.
- Next select the tab [Colors], change to the desired colour and press [OK]

[image]

[image]

if you are not on windows 7 you will need to do the same with 'defaults'.
(It is a known bug on windows 7 that setting it for the current session also sets it as the default).

Screenshot of a new cmd.exe after changing the setting and closing the old shell:

[image]

Comment: I believe that got it Hennes, I chost default instead of properties and tried it in two different directories and it opened with my changed colors so hopefully it works now. Sorry I forgot to say that it was Win7

Answer (score 2):

You can use the color command. Detailed the use of the method is: sets the default console foreground and background colors. - the first as the background, the second is prospect. One of each number can be any of the following values:

```
0 = Black       8 = Gray
1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
2 = Green       A = Light Green
3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
4 = Red         C = Light Red
5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
7 = White       F = Bright White
```

For example: "COLOR fc" produce bright red in bright white

Comment: The result of `color` doesn't persist across command prompt sessions.